# Is there an option to enable overloading of user-defined symbols in cvc4 for SMT input?

Tags: smt, cvc4

In versions through 1.2 of the SMT-LIB language, overloading of user-defined symbols was allowed. Since version 2.0 of standard, overloading is restricted to theory symbol.

Nevertheless, some SMT-solvers still allow overloading of user-defined symbols and that happens to be handy for my use case: proof obligations are easily generated automatically with overloading, not so much without...  I would like to add cvc4 to my portfolio of SMT solvers, but I found out that it produces a parsing error on overloaded user-symbols.

I am aware that this is the correct way to be compliant with the SMT-LIB standard, but I would like to know the following: *Is there an option to CVC4 that disables such check and where the parser is able to disambiguate overloaded user symbols?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, CVC4 does not have an option to support overloaded user symbols.  Each user symbol must be unique.